# Why does getSystemCpuLoad() returns negative value

Tags: java, memory, cpu-usage

I need to get the **CPU usage** and **memory usage** using Java. Found the **getSystemCpuLoad()** of [com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getProcessCpuLoad()). According to docs, it returns a value between 0.0 and 1.0. but I am getting -1 always. According to docs, this is returned when the value is not available. But why does it always return negative value. Is there any property which I need to change in order to fetch correct values?

If not, appreciate if someone can suggest any other approach to get CPU usage and memory usage.

My code includes:

```
OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystemMXBean = (OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
System.out.println(operatingSystemMXBean.getSystemCpuLoad());
```

Comment: What does `getProcessCpuLoad` return? This may be a privilege issue.

Comment: can we see how are you calling/using that?

Comment: The docs does say " a negative value if not available." The question then is what kind of platform are you running on, and what kind/version of the JVM are you running.

Comment: What does `GetLastError` say?

Comment: @Kayaman - getProcessCpuLoad also returns -1.0

Comment: @nos - um working on Windows 7 environment with Java 8 (eclipse is pointed to java 8 and PATH is configured to Java 7) Hope this is not an issue.

Comment: @RustyX - GetLastError returns 0.

Comment: Try to run eclipse as administrator

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getSystemCpuLoad()) really only says that the method returns a negative value if the information could not be accessed **for some reason**.
It could, for example, be so because the data is not *yet* available or perhaps because you do not have the *privilege(s)* necessary to retrieve this information.

---

**OperatingSystemMXBean** *does* seem to need a little bit of time to gather data before **getSystemCpuLoad** starts returning anything useful.

The following code shows how one can test this phenomenon.

```
OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystemMXBean = (OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
while(System.currentTimeMillis() < t + 5000) {
  System.out.println(operatingSystemMXBean.getSystemCpuLoad());
  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
}
```

---

Something I have personally experienced is that when this function is being executed as a *windows service* by a user that is not a member of either the *Performance Log Users* or the *Performance Monitor Users* groups, the function will always return -1 since the user does not have the necessary privileges (to make the system calls, which is what is done in the end).